# Difference between LinkURL and Permalink at Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr

**What is the difference? permalink seems to work perfectly.**

```
<div class="tumblr-photo">
<a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" /></a>
```

**LinkURL generates my blog link. Only goes back to the front and not into the post.**

```
<a href="{LinkURL}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" /></a>
```

Is there annything I am doing wrong or is it OK to use permalink? Tumblr said I was missing LinkOpenTag or LinkURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Click-through URLs for Tumblr's Photo Post Type**

Tumblr provides support for *click-through* URLs on **Photo Posts ONLY**. This allows the post creator to specify an alternative URL to visit when a user clicks the photo. If the post creator doesn't set a *click-through* it defaults to the permalink URL.

**How to add a click-through?**

When the user creates a photo post, hover the image and add the URL:

[image]

Here is example, live: http://mikedidthis-so.tumblr.com/

**Is it wrong?**

To answer the OPs question, it's not wrong, but I wouldn't advise it. You should never define the anchor yourself, let the theme variables take care of it.

```
{LinkOpenTag}
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
{LinkCloseTag}
```

When the theme is parsed, depending on the theme options, it will also add `target="_blank"` to the generated anchor.

**Using {LinkURL}**

The variable `{LinkURL}` should be used to show the `click-through` link as an standalone anchor / text. Example:

```
{block:LinkURL}
<a href="{LinkURL}">Find out more here</a>
{/block:LinkURL}
```

**Reference**

Photo Post Variables: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts

Comment: ok, but when I am using linkopentag it opens in a new preview window of the image. I only want to be redirected to instagram picture or permalink, depends on where the image is from. So what should I use instead of linkopentag? Because linkopentag generates this preview window when it is a normal photopost from my dashboard.

Comment: @Sindre I don't follow. Is the user setting the instagram URL as a click-through on the photo post? Also to clarify, click-through's only apply to Photo Posts, not Photoset Posts.

Comment: If I am adding a picture from instagram or another source. I want it to be redirected to this source. If I am posting a photo-post from dashboard I only want it to be redirected to permalink of photo-post and not to a preview of the image. (tumblrs standard preview setting.) Clicking the back-button in top left corner redirects to permalink. This is all happening if I am using linkopentag. Problems is preview window, I want it to go to the source of image without the preview first.

Comment: @Sindre You have to set the click-through link to the instagram URL when you create the post via the dashboard, and use the correct theme syntax to render click-throughs. As with your other questions, you display lack of minimal understanding and I don't know how to make this more clear.

Comment: I understand the linkopentag makes it work if I post true instagram app. The problem is with linkopentag. Linkopentag also activate tumblrs preview of images. Lightbox gets enabled.

Comment: Have you added the code from the answer? Have you set a click-through URL for the photo post? This is my last comment. I am here to help, but you lack understanding / effort. I have updated the answer to be as clear as possible. As for apps, I have no idea, and that is another question.